# Reading checkboxes values with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a little bit problem  with reading datas from checkboxes.

```
 {foreach value=artist2 from=$artist}
                <br />

                   <input type="checkbox" name="artist[]" value="{$artist2.MOVIE_ID}-{$artist2.PERSON_ID}" { in_array array=$item match=$artist2.NAME_SURNAME returnvalue="CHECKED" }>{$artist2.NAME_SURNAME}<br />

                <hr />
                {/foreach}
                   <p align="right">  <a style="float: right" href='javascript:void(null);' onclick="deleteData();" ><input type="submit" name="removeArtistFromMovie" onclick="showMessage('Seçilen oyuncu(lar) başarıyla silindi')" value="Seçilenleri Sil" id="value"</p></a>
                <br >
                  </form>
```

I produce checkboxes like that and in my js file:

I try this

```
function deleteData(){
    var artistIds = new Array();

    $("input[@type=artist[]][@checked]").each(function(){
        artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

alert(artistIds);



$.post('/management/deleteDataAjax2', 
       { json: JSON.stringify({'artistIds': artistIds}) },
       function(response){
        alert("Başarıyla silindi");
        window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
});



}
```

However, above code does not take the values of checkboxes which is checked. Why ?

**Finally**

I think problem is here because the page does not go to js.

```
<form name=form1 method=post action=# onsubmit='return validate(this)'>

                <br />

                   <input type="checkbox" name="artist[]" value="{$artist2.MOVIE_ID}-{$artist2.PERSON_ID}"  />{$artist2.NAME_SURNAME}<br />


                <hr />



                {/foreach}
                <p align="right">
                <a style="float: right" href='javascript:void(null);' onclick="deleteData();" ><br />
                    <input type="button" name="checkArtistButton" value="Seçilenleri Sil" id="ajaxCheckbox" /></a></p>
                <br >
                  </form>
```

and this is my  js

```
function deleteData(){

    var artistIds = [];
$('#ajaxCheckbox').click(function() {
    $("input[name='artist[]']:checked").each(function() {
        artistIds.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
    alert(artistIds);
});​
​    



$.post('/management/deleteDataAjax2', 
       { json: JSON.stringify({'artistIds': artistIds}) },
       function(response){
        alert("Başarıyla silindi");
        window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
});



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
$("input[@type=artist[]][@checked]").each(function(){
```

try

```
$("input[name='artist[]']:checked").each(function(){
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/9u9Xe/)

### note

I think you mean to get the value of the checkboxes - as looking at your markup they do not have `id` attributes - use `.val()` instead of `attr('id')` to get the value

### Update

You are now setting up an event handler on the click of an anchor ... change this

```
function deleteData() {
    var artistIds = [];
    $('#ajaxCheckbox').click(function () {
        $("input[name='artist[]']:checked").each(function () {
            artistIds.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });
        alert(artistIds);
    });​​
```

to this

```
function deleteData() {
    var artistIds = [];
    $("input[name='artist[]']:checked").each(function () {
        artistIds.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(artistIds);
```

the `deleteData` function is already called `onclick`

Comment: this still is a empty message alert(artistIds); :S

Comment: @Chandresh The example works. The problem is that your inputs don't have IDs. Change to code to take the .val()

Comment: your code is work in jsfiddle but when i click button nothing happens :S

Comment: @MertMETİN updated answer - you really need to learn JavaScript and jQuery (if you continue to use it)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:checked` selector instead of `[@checked]` (btw, you do not use `@` in CSS property selectors). You also used the wrong property selector for the name. I've also simplified your code a bit; your use-case is perfect to use `.map(..).get()`

```
var artistIDs = $("input[name='artist[]']:checked").map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/sBmdC/

Comment: +1 for working solution ... one question for me ... why `map()` instead of `each()` ? (works fine with `each()` also - see my answer and example code)

Comment: `map()` reduces the collection to an object containing the return values of the function passed to it, then `.get()` returns a plain array. As you can see, the `.push()` is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try below line of code:

```
var artistIds = Array();
$("input[name=artist[]]:checked").each(function(index){
     artistIds[index] = $(this).val();
});
```

This may work for you..

Comment: alert(artistIds); still is empty :S